# DateTime conversoin for DB querying

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I need to convert `DateTime` to string for purposes of DB querying.

I thought to do something like

```
_endTime.ToString(_isoDateTimeFormat.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern)
```

It works with MySQL, but SQL Server causes problems.

The final string looks like `2012-03-01 15:59:00Z` seems z not supposed to be there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to a string? Is it stored as text in your database? If so, why?

Comment: why don't you just remove the z?

Comment: I need to enter it to my query string

Comment: @NightWalker: Why would you want to do that instead of using a query parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be performing a text conversion at all.

You should be storing the data as a DATETIME (or whatever the corresponding type is in the database) and then you should be specifying the value in the query using a parameter, not including it in the SQL.

That way you don't need any string conversions in the first place.

*Always* pass values via parameters unless you have some really, *really* good reason why you *absolutely have* to include it in the SQL directly. Using parameters:

- Protects you from SQL injection attacks
- Removes conversion annoyances like this one
- Keeps your code and data more logically separated